# Parse request took too long to process

Tags: parse-platform

Is anyone getting this error from Parse when they try to access the database UI?

This just started happening so I'm wondering what's going on.

{"code":2,"error":"the request took too long to process"}

If so, it a Parse issue or something on my end? If it's on my end, where might I begin to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they're having some trouble today:
[Parse.com Status Page](https://status.parse.com/)